# How do you set a fixed event size?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use fullcalendar.io to create a daily agenda. I have an event that looks like this:

```
events: [{
            title: "this be the test yo",
            duration: 3600,
            durationEditable: false,
            start: '2018-04-07T02:00:00',
            end: '2018-04-07T03:00:00'
        }],
```

Setting *'durationEditable'* to false seems to have a bug. I can't change the event size by dragging the bottom of the event anymore, but when I try to drag the event to a new time slot, the event changes duration length. It seems like the top of the event dom element is still allowing changes.

Comment: to make this work, I removed the resizer elements on the eventRender event. It's a hack, but with that glaring bug in there, I don't know what else to try.

Comment: have you raised a bug about this with the fullCalendar maintainers? https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs

Comment: what does the property ´duration: 3600´ do in your code? There is no such event property in the documentation as far as i know. also post the code of your eventRender, eventDrop and eventResize functions if you happen to use those in your code